# Strange MD5 generation to email link issue

Tags: php, jquery, md5, urlencode

I am having a strange problem with verification links that I send to users. For some reason, there is an extra space inserted in the MD5 string that gets encoded to "%20" and messes up my verification link.

I have the following simple PHP to generate MD5 verification string:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='unique_id' value='" . md5($event['date_submitted']) . "' />";
```

Date submitted is of the format `2012-09-19 16:21:19`.

I have the following jQuery which grabs the string and `POST`s an update to the database with the unique ID as well as emails the link to the user:

```
$("#form1_review_form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var email = $(this).find("input[name='email']").val(),
        message = message_box.val(),
        alloc_id = $(this).find("input[name='alloc_id']").val(),
        unique_id = $(this).find("input[name='unique_id']").val();

        var informed_message = "<a href='MY_DOMAIN/MY_PHP_FILE.php?id=" + unique_id + "&alloc_id=" + alloc_id + "'>Click here</a>!</p>";
        mail(email, "", "FROM", "SUBJECT", informed_message, "");

        $.post(
            "update_form_url.php",
            { update: "lead_revise", alloc_id: alloc_id, unique_id: unique_id },
            function(data) {
                // do stuff
            }
        );  
});
```

And `mail()` in the above code is a wrapper that makes a `POST` request to a PHP file that uses PHP `mail()` to send an email.

Any ideas why a space is getting added and therefore encoded to "%20"? Because in the database, the `unique_id` field does not contain any spaces and the MD5 of the date doesn't contain any spaces.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: start debugging... check if the space is in the hidden form field when the page is built. check the _get/_post stuff as things flow around.

Comment: Im confused, can you sent emails using javascript? Why dont you create the url in "update_form_url.php" and sent it from there? eddit: Ah, you have a javascript function `mail` that posts to a php file? I'd suggest you dont do that, other can sent emails using your server that way...

Answer (score 0):

That's normal, please read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

And if you want to remove them, you can always use `trim`

I was hasty, let me explain a proper solution. I suggest starting to make some debugging, does the space appear in PHP? simply echo it and see the results. Use console log in JS, and keep us updated. Also if the md5 is 32 digits long and a " " appears at end(33rd digit), why not trim it? But i doubt it appears in php

Comment: It is normal that space is encoded to `%20`. But the question was: "Any ideas why a space is getting added and therefore encoded to "%20"?"

Comment: My bad then, you should chill out guys xD. Trim would fix all his problems, regarding of where the " " comes from.

Comment: @AlexandruCalin so would you suggest just putting trim around my md5 generation?

Comment: I was hasty, let me explain a proper solution. I suggest starting to make some debugging, does the space appear in PHP? simply echo it and see the results. Use console log in JS, and keep us updated. Also if the md5 is 32 digits long and a " " appears at end(33rd digit), why not trim it? But i doubt it appears in php

Comment: @AlexandruCalin These are good advice, you should edit your answer.

Comment: @AlexandruCalin unfortunately the space never seems to appear in the echoed PHP. Also, the space appears at different parts in the MD5 string for different unique_id with no discernable pattern. I haven't seen a space at the end yet

Comment: There is nothing in your code that you posted, that could've caused such thing, so it's a little difficult to approach the real problem. You could double check your code, but if you don't find a problem, i suppose you could leave it this way, and when you are doing the link activation let's say: `www.someurl.com/?md5=fdfs988d9%20d3d09f%20` yo could apply $md5 = str_replace(' ', '', urldecode($_GET['md5'])); And match the variable `$md5` against your database to check if the activation is valid.

Comment: This is in case the md5 didn't loose it's integrity and simply got some extra spaces in between.